Pyhton doesn't wait for subprocess.call to finish
I am running a python script which calls powershell on windows. But it seems like python doesn't wait for the powershell script to finish before moving on (or at least it seems so). Here is my code:
import numpy as np
import subprocess 

filename = "out_test.txt"

subprocess.call(r"powershell.exe & '.\SIMION 8.1.lnk' fly --recording-output=.\out_test.txt .\optimize_setup.iob")

data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1)
print(len(data))

The function called in subprocess.call works fine when I use it in powershell itself. Basically it runs a program and saves the output in out_test.txt However when I run from Python, I get this error: FileNotFoundError: out_test.txt not found. So basically the python script moves to the data = np.loadtxt(filename,skiprows=1) line, without waiting for the subprocess.call to actually generate the file. The files will be of different lengths, so the wait time would vary so I don't want to add by hand a wait time (e.g. using time.sleep(1)). How can I make sure python waits for the subprocess.call to finish? Thank you!
Online I see that python should automatically wait for subprocess.call but it doesn't. I tried subprocess.run but I get the same result.

what makes you think subprocess.call is not waiting for powershell to finish ? is it not running under the expected time? FileNotFoundError: out_test.txt not found. could simply mean that Python didn't found that file in the relative path and the issue could be easily fixed by using absolute path in both, Python and the PowerShell CLI call

The path is fine, if I try to load the file later, once it exists in the folder it works fine. The error only comes when I call the loadtxt right after the subprocess.call

if you run & '.\SIMION 8.1.lnk' fly --recording-output=.\out_test.txt .\optimize_setup.iob from powershell itself, does it block the terminal or do you get control back instantly ?

I get control basically instantly once the program finishes running

so that's the reason why subprocess.call interprets the next lines instantly... I'll assume that whatever points to '.\SIMION 8.1.lnk' is an app that will start a subprocess to do the work, in which case you would need to invoke it using Start-Process -Wait from PowerShell to force a synchronized invocation, basically so that PowerShell waits for not only the started process but also for all subprocesses started by it

as aside, I don't understand why you need powershell to invoke an external process from python. why not just invoke that external process from python itself and remove the extra complexity ?

How would I do that? I thought I need to do it through terminal

I think you need to explain in your question what exactly is SIMION 8.1.lnk (not the shortcut but what it points to)

This is a commercially available software: https://simion.com/. I assume the shortcut points to the installation location which is Program Files

so go to that lnk right click properties and look for "Target" to see where it points to then from python you can simply subprocess.Run that target with the arguments. you don't need powershell for this

I am not sure I understand. How would I even pass arguments in this case? The example above is highly simplified, in practice I need to call that software with different parameters, obtained inside the Python script.

well just like how you're doing with powershell.exe, you can comma separate the args in the array like: subprocess.run(['path\to\simion.exe', 'fly', '--recording-output=.\out_test.txt', '.\optimize_setup.iob', ...], ...)

Subprocess.run is the recommended method as described in the docs to use if you are developing new code (will block until the process ends), and if you want to do stuff in the background you can use Subprocess.Popen() and then do a join() call when you want to block until its completed.
I can't run your code but the issue you are likely running into is the process finished -- but windows IO has not finished. This often happens with big files where you can't access them the exact second they are saved.
If you are sure the file should exist, it usually does not take too long. I have delt with this like so -- not sure of any other method:
while True:
 time.sleep(.25) # avoid stressing the cpu and let operation 
 try:
  x = np.loadtext(my_file)
  if x is empty ... validate however you want:
   continue

  else:
   break
 except #whatever error numpy throws:
     continue
    
# open file and do logic



  


This doesn't seem to work. If I use this, the file is found it the path, but it appears to be empty.

Perhaps the file name has been created and found in the directory, but it is still being written.

So how can I deal with that without having a fixed wait time for all files?

see my edit -- either try catch the open if numpy throws issues or validate the numpy array and keep reopening it.  These sort of problems will always be resolved by repeatedly polling as you can't control the os much.
